Apply Texture Projection to Specific Pose (not Rest Position), While Keeping the Animation Intact
I want to apply texture projection on a game character from Adobe Mixamo. I started Blender with this game character, which includes an animation. Since the final result in my game will use the running animation, it makes sense to apply texturing via texture projection on a frame of this animation. However, when I try to project a texture onto my character, I see a pose/rest position that doesn't match the final position the game character takes in the end result. Applying a texture via texture projection on the pose/rest position skeleton isn't logical in this case.
What I have tried:
I tried changing the rest position to the desired pose where I want to project a texture on to (the first frame of my animation). Unfortunately, this resulted in the following warning: "Actions on armature will be destroyed by new rest pose." This is not what I want because, apart from the texture, everything is perfect, and I want everything to remain intact.
Some images for clarification:
The first frame of my animated model:

The image I want to project on it as a texture

Demonstrating the problem: What my model looks like when I open the UV editing tab (to perform texture projection)

How can perform texture projection on my model using the first frame of the animation as the pose?

You need to bake the projected texture to a mesh with UVs. Like this

@Jakemoyo thanks for your comment! I watched that video a few times but I am unsure how that could help me to project my 2d image onto my mesh (running pose). Could you elaborate further?

You project the image onto one model, then create a "low-poly" (not necessarily lower poly count, just one with 'real topo' and UV maps), that matches it and bake the diffuse from the projected model to the low-poly one. Then once it's in a texture it will stick to the low-poly models verts without projection.
